# How to add a length/distance scale to a plot

Tags: r, plot

I have created a scatterplot using the `plot()` function. This plot represents multiple territories in a given area but I want to give a sense to the scale of these territories.

It is a large dataset and I am also using `points()` to help include all information onto one plot. Please see the attached code.

```
plot(c.aus1.1FG$x.position,c.aus1.1FG$y.position,ylim=c(80,130),xlim=c(140,240),xaxt='n',yaxt= 'n',pch=18,col="yellow",xlab="", ylab="",cex=0.75)
points(c.aus1.2FG$x.position,c.aus1.2FG$y.position,pch=18, col="yellow",cex=0.75)
points(c.aus1.3FG$x.position,c.aus1.3FG$y.position,pch=18, col="yellow", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus2.1FG$x.position,c.aus2.1FG$y.position,pch=18, col="blue", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus2.2FG$x.position,c.aus2.2FG$y.position,pch=18, col="blue", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus3.1FG$x.position,c.aus3.1FG$y.position,pch=18, col="dark red", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus3.2FG$x.position,c.aus3.2FG$y.position,pch=18, col="dark red", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus3.3FG$x.position,c.aus3.3FG$y.position,pch=18, col="dark red", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus4.1FG$x.position,c.aus4.1FG$y.position,pch=18, col="orange", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus4.2FG$x.position,c.aus4.2FG$y.position,pch=18, col="orange", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus4.3FG$x.position,c.aus4.3FG$y.position,pch=18, col="orange", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus4.4FG$x.position,c.aus4.4FG$y.position,pch=18, col="orange", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus5.1FG$x.position,c.aus5.1FG$y.position,pch=18, col="dark green", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus5.2FG$x.position,c.aus5.2FG$y.position,pch=18, col="dark green", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus5.3FG$x.position,c.aus5.3FG$y.position,pch=18, col="dark green", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus6.1FG$x.position,c.aus6.1FG$y.position,pch=18, col="purple", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus6.2FG$x.position,c.aus6.2FG$y.position,pch=18, col="purple", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus6.3FG$x.position,c.aus6.3FG$y.position,pch=18, col="purple", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus6.4FG$x.position,c.aus6.4FG$y.position,pch=18, col="purple", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus7.1FG$x.position,c.aus7.1FG$y.position,pch=18, cex=0.75)
points(c.aus7.2FG$x.position,c.aus7.2FG$y.position,pch=18, cex=0.75)
points(c.aus7.3FG$x.position,c.aus7.3FG$y.position,pch=18, cex=0.75)
points(c.aus8.1FG$x.position,c.aus8.1FG$y.position,pch=18,col="red", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus8.2FG$x.position,c.aus8.2FG$y.position,pch=18,col="red", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus8.3FG$x.position,c.aus8.3FG$y.position,pch=18,col="red", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus8.4FG$x.position,c.aus8.4FG$y.position,pch=18,col="red", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus9.1FG$x.position,c.aus9.1FG$y.position,pch=18, col="grey", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus9.2FG$x.position,c.aus9.2FG$y.position,pch=18, col="grey", cex=0.75)
points(c.aus9.3FG$x.position,c.aus9.3FG$y.position,pch=18, col="grey", cex=0.75)
```

This provides the following plot. How do you add a distance scale to the plot at the top right/bottom right?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are plotting spatial data, you might as well use `coordinates` and `scalebar` from the `raster` package:

```
library(raster)

# generate x and y coordinate and grouping variable P
set.seed(1)
x = runif(min = 0, max = 100, n = 20)
y = runif(min = 200, max = 400, n = 20)
P = rep(1:4, each = 5, len = 20)    # first 4 only.

# generate a data frame
my_points = data.frame(x,y,P)

# define x and y as coordinates, creates a SpatialPointsDataFrame
coordinates(my_points)<-~x+y

# plot the point data
plot(my_points, col=my_points$P, pch=3, axes=T)

# add scale bar
scalebar(d = 50, xy = c(100,350), type = 'bar', divs = 2, below = 'm')
```

If you don't want to use `raster`, you can manually create a bar, perhaps like this:

```
# or manual, without raster package
plot(x,y, col=P, pch=3)

# add a line for scale, covering distance between x0 and x1
segments(x0 = 80, x1 = 100, y0 = 350, y1 = 350, lwd=3, lend=2)

# alternative with an arrow
arrows(x0 = 80, x1 = 100, y0 = 350, y1 = 350, lwd=3, lend=2, code = 3, angle = 90, len=0.1)

# add text label to line
text(x = 90, y =  360, labels = '20 m')
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with sp package, maybe ?

```
library(sp)

# dumb data
data<-data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10),col=c(rep('a',5),rep('b',5)))
# coordinates (see also proj4string!)
coordinates(data)<-~x+y

summary(data)

# set scale and text
scale = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(), 
             offset = c(0.2,0.03), scale = 0.2, fill=c("transparent","black"))

start = list("sp.text", c(0.2,0.01), "0")
end= list("sp.text", c(0.4,0.01), "0.2")

# plot result with scales, key, 
map<-spplot(data,scales = list(draw = TRUE),
       key.space=list(x=0.1,y=0.93,corner=c(0,1)),
       sp.layout=list(scale,start,end),
       main='simple map'
       )

print(map)
```

Look here also :[sp graphic examples](http://rspatial.r-forge.r-project.org/gallery/)

Comment: I am still a little lost, how can this function be used on a mixture of plot() and points()?

Comment: Did you try this code in a r console ? It's a proposition with a package especially designed to handle spatial data. Look at the link bellow the code. So, instead of manually adding points to a plot, keep data in a well organised data.frame with x,y columns, make a coordinate spatial object (can be projected), and plot from there.